# Not able to debug desktop in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I am trying to start Windows app for first time with default Flutter Project but it's showing this error,

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Can't load AOT data from {#project-path}\build\windows\runner\Debug\data\app.so; no such file.
Unable to start engine without AOT data.
Failed to create view controller.
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly, or never started.
Error launching application on Windows.
Exited (sigterm)
```

here is my `flutter doctor -v` result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1526], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.10.2 at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 097d3313d8 (3 days ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
    • Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\panth\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32210.238
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\panth\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1526]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.56

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Here is what i have already tried

1. [copy paste app.so file from **./build/windows** to **./build/windows/runner/Debug/data**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71132188/flutter-error-when-trying-to-debug-windows-app/71176349#71176349)
   this is an inefficient solution, since hot reload doesn't work.
2. [downgrade visual studio to 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71144415/15152948)
   I tried to downgrade visual studio to 2019, and then deleted windows folder form root directory, then ran `flutter clean` and `flutter create .`. then started debug and this error happened

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly, or never started.
Error launching application on Windows.
Exited (sigterm)
```

so i uninstalled visual studio and installed 2022 version back.

3. Also tried `flutter clean` had no effect.

What can I do for this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Error when trying to debug Windows App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71132188/flutter-error-when-trying-to-debug-windows-app)

Comment: @catalin, that was my first try as mentioned above, and is a very inefficient solution

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "that". The other question is the same as this one, and apparently SO automatically added the comment when flagged as duplicate. Also, the other question has multiple answers. You might want to scroll beyond the first one.

Comment: @catalin i have done that, and no solution works, yes que is similar but no solution there works for me.

Comment: Did you really try editing `windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt` to replace `$<CONFIG>` with `Debug` ?  Anyway, whether they work or not, this question _is_ a duplicate of the other one, not just similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97086) in the version of CMake shipped with the latest update to Visual Studio 2022. There is currently no good workaround other than using an earlier version of VS, but you can follow that issue for updates.

Comment: are you suggesting me to downgrade visual studio 2022 to 2019. btw, i am on windows machine.

Comment: if you are asking to downgrade then, can you look into the question, i updated have question's (2) point which i have tried

Answer (score 0):

When you downgraded to Visual Studio 2019, did you simply delete Visual Studio 2022?

I found that when I simply deleted Visual Studio 2022, I had your same error. I had success by uninstalling then reinstalling "Desktop development with C++" from my Visual Studio 2019, followed by `flutter clean` and `flutter run -d windows`.

Comment: i have tried all permutations, downgrading/upgrading, uninstall and then reinstall with 2019, etc.,. nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed from this github issue.[flutter github issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71132188/flutter-error-when-trying-to-debug-windows-app)